# css to produce a curve effect at the top of a div

Tags: css

I'm looking for a hand to produce the curve effect in this image.
[image]

At the moment I have a full width div of the same background-color, with a div above it using a class with the following:

```
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #ffecd8;
    border-radius: 100%/100px 100px 0 0;
    transform: translateY(-55px);
```

It's almost there but the top of the curve seems flat. Can anyone suggest a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a combination of `clip-path` and `ellipse`.

the syntax of ellipse is: 
`[radius-x] [radius-y] at [position-x] [position-y]`

```css
div {
  clip-path: ellipse(150% 100% at 50% 100%);
}


/* for visualization purpose only */
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```